# How to properly handle camera intent in android if the user chooses some random camera app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, android-camera-intent

I am working on a project where I am using a camera intent to take picture of the user. The code is typical, I create an intent and give it the output file's URI, and onActivityResult, I get the image saved in the given uri, so the simplified code looks something like this:

```java
Uri outputFileURI; //<-- this is where the output picture should be
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileURI);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And then,

```java
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  outputFileURI; // <-- the image is saved in this uri by the camera
  // do something with the uri
}
```

This works nicely if we use the default camera app of the phone.

### The Problem

If the user chooses a different camera app (in this case, the users are selecting [PicsArt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/?id=com.pdetailsicsart.studio&hl=en_US&gl=US) app), this doesnot work. ie, the picsArt app is not saving the image in the uri. The user could have chosen any arbitrary camera app, so what is the proper way to fix this issue? Is it possible to restrict the user to only use the default camera app? Or should I use [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) or something similar?

Comment: `the picsArt app is not saving the image in the uri. ` But does it save it somewhere in a file? Please investigate.

Comment: Also investigate the whole set of bundle in the received intent. Look which info it provides. If you are lucky data.getData() is the uri.

Comment: yes, If I open the default gallery of my phone, it shows the the photo. The photo is saved in the picsArt's internal storage. And thanks for the advice, I'll check the `data.getData()`

Answer (score 2):

> This works nicely if we use the default camera app of the phone

It might for the few devices that you tested out of the tens of thousands of device models that exist. Pre-installed camera apps are as likely as third-party apps to have bugs, and over the years, [plenty of pre-installed camera apps have had bugs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html), including ones like the one that you cite for PicsArt.

> If the user chooses a different camera app (in this case, the users are selecting PicsArt app), this doesnot work. ie, the picsArt app is not saving the image in the uri

File a bug with PicsArt. But, again, do not assume that "default camera app" means "always works" and do not assume that "different camera app" means "never works".

> so what is the proper way to fix this issue?

That would be a question for your managers, most likely. Basically, you have two main options:

1. Tell the user "sorry, but the camera app that you used does not work nicely with other apps — please consider trying X", where X is the name of some camera app that you have tested and believe is likely to be reliable. For example, I tend to use Open Camera as my reference app.
2. Do not rely upon `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and instead take photos directly from your app, such as using CameraX as you mentioned. On the plus side, you have complete control. On the minus side, this is a lot more work, and camera hardware compatibility offers its own set of headaches.

Personally, my recommendation between the two would come down to how critical it is that your app be able to take photos. If the app is useless without those photos, take the photos directly from your app, and budget the engineering and QA time for both the initial development and ongoing maintenance. If the app can be used without photos, I would continue using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and just "gracefully degrade" if the user's chosen camera app does not work well.